# Mongoose showing null object though collection exists in MongoDB

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I try to fetch data from local mongodb using mongoose in my ExpressJS App.
But couldn't fetch data.

I have tried to use mongoose and mongojs to retrive data from mongodb.

Even  tried with passing right collection name in schema.

Here is my code.

### using monogjs(blog.js)

```
var mongojs = require('mongojs');


      var db = mongojs('mongodb://localhost:27017/mydb', ['blogs']);

    // On Connection
    db.on('connect', function () {
    console.log('Mongo JS database connected')
    });
    //On Error
    db.on('error', function (err) {
    console.log('Mongo JS database error', err)
    });

    module.exports.getBlogs = function(res) {
    //var data = db.blogs.find();
    db.blogs.find({}, (rec, res)=>{
    if(rec){
      res.json(rec);
      console.log('Data '+ rec)
    }else{
      console.log('No Data '+ rec)
    }
    });
    }
```

### using mongoose(blogs.js)

```
----------------------
    const mongoose = require('mongoose');
    const config = require('../config/database');
    const DataSchema = mongoose.Schema ({
            "title": { type: String },
        "Description": { type: String },
        "Rate": { type: Number }
     }, { collection : 'Datas' });

    const Datas = module.exports = mongoose.model('Datas', DataSchema);
    //const Datas = module.exports = mongoose.model('Datas', DataSchema, 
    'Datas');

    module.exports.getblogs = function(){
    Data.find({}, (recs)=>{
        if(recs){
            console.log('Records found' + recs)
        }else{
            console.log('Records not found');
        }
    });
```

Comment: Please provide more detail with connection and some example code.

Comment: module.exports = {
  // configure the code below with your username, password and mlab database information
  //database: 'mongodb://<username>:<password>@ds12226.mlab.com:12226/meanauthapp',   //prod
  database: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/meanauth',    //dev
  secret: 'yoursecret'
}

Answer (score 0):

Try Give below code may be it's work

Insert One Record in Mongodb collections

```
const {MongoClient, ObjectID} = require('mongodb');//destructre the MongoClient object

var obj = new ObjectID();
console.log(obj);
const url  = "mongodb://localhost:27017/";
 var user ={name:'Prashant',Age:22};
 var {name}=user ; //destructre the user object
 console.log(name);
 MongoClient.connect(url,function(err,db){
   if(err) throw err;
   var dbo=db.db("TodoApp");
   var myobj ={
     name:"Prashant",
     address:"kanpur",
     Age:22,
     Work:"Accord"
   };
   dbo.collection("user").insertOne(myobj,function(err,res){
     if(err) throw err;
     console.log(res.ops[0]._id.getTimestamp());
     db.close();
   });
 });
```

Fetching one record form Mongodb collections.

```
const {mongoose}= require('./../server/db/mongoose');
const {Todo} = require('./../server/models/todo');
const {ObjectID} = require('mongodb');
const {User}    = require('./../server/models/user');
var id= '5b13960c4730b43f80cef6af';

if(!ObjectID.isValid(id)){
  console.log('Id not valid');
};

Todo.find({
  _id: id
}).then((todos)=>{
  console.log('Tdod',todos);
});

Todo.findOne({
  _id: id
}).then((todo)=>{
  console.log('Todo',todo);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**Note** : Please confirm that **mongodb** is proper configure install and its run on your local machine

Sample example :

**database.js** //databse connection

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const logger = require('../helper/logger');

mongoose.Promise = global.Promise;
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/localDb');
mongoose.connection.on('error', (err) => {
  logger.error(err);
});
```

**userModel.js** //Model File

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const { Schema } = mongoose;

const userSchema = new Schema({

  firstName: {
    type: String,
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
  },
  profilePic: { type: String },
}, { collection: 'users', timestamps: true });
const User = mongoose.model('users', userSchema);
module.exports = User;
```

**server.js** // create server

```
const app = require('express')();

require('./config/database.js'); //connection file


// Body Parse
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: '50mb' }));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: '50mb', extended: true }));


const server = http.createServer(app);

server.listen(process.env.PORT, () => {
  logger.info(`Express server listening on port ${process.env.PORT}`);
});
```